# В телеботе, при тапе на одну кнопку - выводится еще кнопка, и при нажатии - финишный текст, а на другую кнопку - цепочку сообщений как реализовать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

помогите новичку с телеботом

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Хочу поговорить")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Часто задаваемые вопросы")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    send_mess = f"<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}</b>. Чем тебе помочь?"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def mess(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip()

    if get_message_bot == "Часто задаваемые вопросы":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Как настроение?")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Ты сегодня выходил гулять или сидел весь день за компьютером?")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        final_message = f"<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, выбери вопрос который интересует, и получи ответ!"

    elif get_message_bot == "Как настроение?":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        final_message = "Отлично. Всего доброго!"

    elif get_message_bot == "Ты сегодня выходил гулять или сидел весь день за компьютером?":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        final_message = """Надоели эти вопросы. До свидания!"""
    else:
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        final_message = f"<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, нажми на кнопки, и получи ответ или напиши"

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатию кнопки "Хочу поговорить", был ответ "О чем будем говорить?", потом после ввода любого текста пользователем, автоматический ответ от бота "Подождите на линии, сегодня или завтра позвоним!" ?

Создавал еще один хендлер, добавлял еще один метод send_message, всегда ловит

```
else:
     markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     final_message = f"<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, нажми на кнопки, и получи ответ или напиши"
```

или не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тоже недавно начал изучать. Попробовал что-то написать, по крайней мере, у меня код работает))

Обновлено:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot=telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Хочу поговорить")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Часто задаваемые вопросы")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    send_mess = f"<b>Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}</b>. Чем тебе помочь?"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

def func2(message):
    if message.text=="Да":
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Подождите на линии, сегодня или завтра позвоним!")
    elif message.text=="Нет":
           bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Удачи! Если что, то связывайтесь с нами снова!")

def func(message):
      if message.text=="Часто задаваемые вопросы":
          mess(message)
      else:
          input=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ты уверен?")
          bot.register_next_step_handler(input, func2)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def mess(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip()
    final_message=""

    if get_message_bot == "Часто задаваемые вопросы":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Как настроение?")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Ты сегодня выходил гулять или сидел весь день за компьютером?")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        final_message = f"<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, выбери вопрос который интересует, и получи ответ!"

    elif get_message_bot == "Как настроение?":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        final_message = "Отлично. Всего доброго!"

    elif get_message_bot == "Ты сегодня выходил гулять или сидел весь день за компьютером?":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        final_message = """Надоели эти вопросы. До свидания!"""

    elif get_message_bot == "Хочу поговорить":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        input=bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "О чем поговорим?")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(input, func)
    
    else:
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        final_message = f"<b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>, нажми на кнопки, и получи ответ или напиши"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Else можно убрать тогда

Comment: Все работает. Отлично. Спасибо!
C Else работает как надо.

Не подскажите, как добавить еще один вопрос, например, пользователь жмет кнопку "Хочу поговорить", и сразу получает смс от бота - "О чем поговорим?", отвечает пользователь, и потом еще одно смс от бота "Ты уверен?", отвечает пользователь, и после сразу бот "Подождите на линии, сегодня или завтра позвоним!" ?

Comment: Обновил ответ)) Вы можете еще вытащить функции func и func2 из `@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])`. Думаю, что будет удобнее))

Comment: Большое спасибо)
Я пока еще очень зеленый новичок) Буду учится дальше)

Как Вам можно скинуть донат? Как с Вами связаться?

Не знаю можно ли здесь публиковать почту или телеграм для связи

Comment: Пожалуйста! Скидывать ничего не надо)) Форум ведь специально создан, чтобы помогать людям) Если ответ действительно правильный, тогда отметьте, пожалуйста, его галочкой) Это для меня будет подарком, так сказать :)

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли. Ваш ответ был решением, как первого, так и второго вопроса в комментариях. Большое спасибо)

Я новичок, синтаксис знаю, код читаю, а работающий код писать обычно не получается. Не хватает сообразительности(

В меня есть еще один вопрос. Если ответите, то буду очень благодарен:

Допустим, пользователь нажал кнопку: "Хочу поговорить", и ему автоматом от бота появилось сообщение "О чем поговорим?". Пользователь резко передумал, и нажал кнопку "Часто задаваемые вопросы", и ему продолжает писать "Ты уверен?". Как можно сделать, чтобы появлялись соответствующие кнопки?

Comment: Я попробую, но уточните, текст "Ты уверен?" должен появляться после нажатия на другую кнопку или же после ответа на вопрос "О чём поговорим?", правильно? Должны ли быть кнопки "Да" или "Нет" на тексте "Ты уверен?"

Comment: Я имею виду, если пользователь нажимает "Хочу поговорить", ему бот отправляет "О чем поговорим?", т.к.сейчас есть. Если пользователь, не хочет отвечать, и жмет на кнопку "Часто задаваемые вопросы", то ему должны показываться кнопки "Как настроение?","Ты сегодня выходил гулять", т.к. и должно быть
Просто сейчас ситуация такая, если нажал на "Хочу поговорить", бот отправляет "О чем поговорим", потом пользователь нажимает "Часто задаваемые вопросы", а бот отвечает "Ты уверен?",что есть неправильно. Я так понимаю бот регистрирует любое смс как следующий шаг и продолжает выполнять функцию до конца

Comment: Я пробывал создать список фраз, таких как "Часто задаваемые вопросы" и т.д., дальше создал функцию, внутри которой цикл for бежит по списку, и если есть в наличии, хотя бы одна фраза, которая написана кнопке, то выполнить функцию mess(message), и перейти, например, к "Часто задаваемым вопросам", если нет, то продолжить выполнять func и func_2. Но в меня не работает, я запутался.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Можете проверять :)

Comment: Вы Гений) Ответили на все вопросы, которые я не мог решить долгое время. Сэкономили мне много времени. Большое спасибо! Удачи Вам!

Кстати, было бы отлично, если бы я держал связь с Вами, например, в телеграмме, и по возможности донатил по немного за решение вопросов, ведь действительно Вы сэкономили много времени мне) Ведь учится самому сложно, хорошо если есть кто поможет сдвинутся с места и идти дальше...

Comment: Донатить ничего не нужно, я сам новичок, и учился на ошибках, и, благодаря форуму, смог хоть как-то развиться! Я очень рад, что смог Вам помочь) Желаю тоже удачи)

Comment: Так же на форуме доступна функция "Общения в чате". Если репутации для этой функции не хватает, Вы всегда можете здесь задать вопрос, Вам помогут люди, которые гораздо лучше меня, ведь благодаря им и их ответам на мои вопросы, я смог помочь найти ответ для Вас

Comment: Я думал, что Вы сеньйор) Все четко и понятно. Огромное человеческое Вам спасибо)